# Update Plots from the Stat Menu

Tags: minitab

I have a data-set I keep updating and want to use some plot of the Stat menu (Pareto, Main Effects, Interaction). Unfortunately it seems not to be possible, only graph from the graph menu seem to be updatable. Does anyone know about Tricks/Macros to update these Plots?

Couldn't find much somewhere else unfortunately, only in another forum that plots from Stat menu aren't updatable